# How to detect if $POST function content if got space then convert to "_" to create folder?

Tags: php, mkdir

I have a problem to detect the $POST function content if space then convert to "dash" to create folder. How to use `str_replace` function to detect the space convert to "_"? For example, if $_POST['function_name'] content is `stack over flow`, then how to convert to content is `stack_over_flow`. Because when dealing with the file system I need to escape the space character with "_". Else if any space in the $POST content, it cannot let me create the folder in the system.

```html
if ($_POST['function_code']!=''){
$function_symbol = "_";
}if ($_POST['activity_code']!=''){
$activity_symbol = "_";
}if ($_POST['sub_activity_code']!=''){
$sub_symbol = "_";
}if ($_POST['transaction_code']!=''){
$transaction_symbol = "_";
}
$folder_name = $_POST['function_code'].$function_symbol.$_POST['function_name'].$_POST['activity_code'].$activity_symbol.$_POST['activity_name'].$_POST['sub_activity_code'].$sub_symbol .$_POST['sub_activity_name'].$_POST['transaction_code'].$transaction_symbol.$_POST['transaction_name'];

$location2 = $folder_location.'/'.$folder_name;
if($parentid == '0'){
    mkdir("dms/$folder_name",0777,true);
        }if ($parentid > '0' ){
            mkdir("dms/$location2",0777,true);
                    }
```

May I know how to use this **str_replace(' ', '_', $folder_name);** code embed to my coding? Hope someone can guide me. Thanks.

Comment: `$location2 = $folder_location.'/'.str_replace(' ', '_', $folder_name);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use str_replace function as following

```
str_replace(' ','_',trim($_POST['function_name']));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use regex php to remove all space:

```
$folder_name = preg_replace('/(\s)+/', '_', $folder_name);
```